# Extract option values from a dropdown list using BeautifulSoup - Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to extract options (eg.AUD) from a dropdown list from the following link: [https://transferwise.com/us]](https://transferwise.com/us%5D)

I tried this

```
import requests
from bs4 import *
twise__url = 'https://transferwise.com/us'
page = requests.get(twise__url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        title = soup.title.text # gets you the text of the <title>(...)</title>
        for itemText in soup.find_all('button', attrs={'class':'btn btn-input btn-input-inverse btn-addon btn-lg dropdown-toggle'}):
            print(itemText))
```

[image]

Expected Output:

```
NZD
EUR
GBP
IND
CZK
MYR
CAD

etc
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I just updated the question

Comment: do you want only the value `AUD`? or also all the info regarding the transfer? What exactly do you want to scrape?

Comment: I want to scrap all the values e.g AUD, GBP

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the currencies, then just use the API.

For example, use the `recent` endpoint:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"
}
currencies = requests.get("https://transferwise.com/gateway/v1/savings/recent", headers=headers).json()

for currency in currencies:
    print(f"{currency['sourceCurrency']} - {currency['targetCurrency']}:")
    print(f"{currency['sendAmount']} -> {currency['savings']}")
```

This prints:

```
EUR - UAH:
58.43 -> 10.13
EUR - INR:
227.39 -> 22.18
EUR - LKR:
18.31 -> 9.16
AUD - GBP:
127.0 -> 12.69
GBP - INR:
20.32 -> 6.8
GBP - EUR:
21.66 -> 5.53
CAD - EUR:
18.66 -> 11.22
PLN - UAH:
88.2 -> 36.53
USD - INR:
19.49 -> 11.75
...
```

There's also a `history` endpoint for the last `30` days for a given pair.

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

import requests

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"
}
history = requests.get("https://transferwise.com/rates/history?source=AUD&target=EUR&length=30", headers=headers).json()
for item in history:
    print(f"{datetime.fromtimestamp(item['time'] / 1000)}")
    print(f"{item['source']} -> {item['target']}: {item['value']}")
```

Output:

```
2020-10-14 02:00:00
AUD -> EUR: 0.6073
2020-10-15 02:00:00
AUD -> EUR: 0.603704
2020-10-16 02:00:00
AUD -> EUR: 0.604669
2020-10-17 02:00:00
AUD -> EUR: 0.603994
2020-10-18 02:00:00
AUD -> EUR: 0.603979
2020-10-19 02:00:00
AUD -> EUR: 0.602059
2020-10-20 02:00:00
AUD -> EUR: 0.596948
2020-10-21 02:00:00
...
```

If, however, you *only* want all the currency short names, try this:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"
}
currencies = requests.get("https://transferwise.com/gateway/v1/savings/recent", headers=headers).json()

output = []
for currency in currencies:
    output.extend([currency['sourceCurrency'], currency['targetCurrency']])

print(sorted(list(set(output))))
```

Output:

```
['AUD', 'BDT', 'CNY', 'CZK', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'HRK', 'HUF', 'IDR', 'INR', 'JPY', 'KES', 'LKR', 'MYR', 'NGN', 'NOK', 'NZD', 'PHP', 'PKR', 'PLN', 'RON', 'RUB', 'SEK', 'SGD', 'TRY', 'UAH', 'USD', 'VND']
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, @itgeek. If you find my answer useful, consider up-voting and/or accepting it.